# Reasonably complete infrared spectral database with data in CSV form?

Tags: spectroscopy, reference-request, ir-spectroscopy

I'm currently developing a neural network that analyses IR spectroscopy signatures. I've found a very complete data set at [The Spectral Database of Organic Compounds](http://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/cre_index.cgi), but data is only available as images, which are not ideal for training neural nets.

Does anyone know of a reasonably comprehensive open database of spectroscopy data that offers data in CSV/tabulated form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, I would think you could fairly easily design some data extraction tools for the AIST database. After all, the X and Y axes are standardized (i.e., $4000-400 \mathrm{cm}^{-1}$).

Beyond AIST, you can find machine-readable JCAMP files from the [NIST WebBook](http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/). There are supposedly ~16,000 spectra, although you'd have to script some way to download them one-by-one.

I think a better bet would be to purchase a database:

- [Bio-Rad](http://www.bio-rad.com/en-ch/product/ir-spectral-databases) sells an IR database. A quick look now indicates that it has ~235,000 spectra and I'm sure it's in an accessible format.
- [NIST](http://www.nist.gov/srd/nist35.cfm) sells a smaller database ~5000 compounds in JCAMP format.

A quick search also turned up:

- [IR Spectra.com](http://www.ir-spectra.com) - claiming ~140,000 spectra in various formats.

Comment: I will mention that while I've heard of efforts to create an IR spectral database (e.g., all those new compound published in journals), nothing significant has appeared. (The [Open Spectral Database](https://osdb.stuchalk.domains.unf.edu) has ~45 spectra.)